# Avoid syncing of Microsoft Office temporary files in Google Backup and Sync for pc

Tags: microsoft-office, google-drive, temporary-files, google-sync

Is there a way to avoid syncing of Microsoft Office temporary files with names starting with "~$" in the new Google Backup and Sync client for pc? I have tried this new client, but it seems this old problem we also saw in the former Google Drive client for pc is still there:

[image]

On the [Choose a sync solution](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7491633) page, Google states that now we can "Use native applications like MS Word and Photoshop". For me it means that there should be no problems like I described. Do I understand something wrong, or is there a way to avoid syncing of temporary MS Office files created automatically for MS Office files stored and edited in the synced folders?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/1240146/file-filters-in-google-backup-and-sync Unfortunately, no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, You may not be able to configure Google Drive to not synchronize these files, but Google Drive can delete these files when you close Microsoft Office by activating the option Always delete both copies.

[image]